# Autostart Python script in Terminal Lubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, lubuntu, python, autostart

I'm using Lubuntu with the ODROID C0. There is a Python script which needs to be autostarted. I navigated to

> [start menu]>preferences>Default applications for LXSession

, then navigated to the autostart tab and added `xterm -e "python /path/to/script.py"`. The xterm autostart works but reads the error

> xterm: Can't execvp "python: No such file or directory

Any ideas about how I can properly configure the autostart of this Python script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use `xterm -e python /path/to/script.py`, without the quotes, instead.

Your `"` quotes aren't behaving the way you want. `xterm -e` is trying to run `"python` with `/path/to/script.py"` as its argument, instead of `python` with `/path/to/script` as its argument. **In this case you can simply omit the quotes.**

In a shell script or when you run a shell interactively, [quotes are treated specially](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) and [quote removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal) is performed. But this does not happen with commands you specify in *LXSession configuration* → *Autostart* → *Manual autostarted applications*.

Fortunately, even though `xterm -e` in Ubuntu will perform [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) on one argument to treat it as a command, it also accepts multiple arguments. That's why `-e` has to be the last option--everything else is interpreted as being part of the command. For example, if you run `xterm -e nano foo`, that opens `foo` in `nano` in an XTerm window. As [`man xterm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xterm.1.html) says:

```
   -e program [ arguments ... ]
           This  option  specifies  the  program  (and  its  command  line
           arguments) to be run in the xterm window.   It  also  sets  the
           window  title  and  icon name to be the basename of the program
           being executed if neither -T nor -n are given  on  the  command
           line.  This must be the last option on the command line.
```

Assuming you're not trying to run a script whose path has spaces in its name, all you have to do  is remove the quotes:

```bash
xterm -e python /path/to/script.py
```

Two other caveats come to mind:

- When the script finishes, `python` quits, and then the XTerm window will quit too. If you don't want this then you can add code to the Python script that waits for user interaction, or you can write a wrapper shell script (or any kind of wrapper script) that runs `python /path/to/script.py` and then waits for user interaction.
- [XTerm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) works fine in Lubuntu but the default GUI terminal emulator is [LXTerminal](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTerminal). In case you would prefer to use that, you can use `lxterminal` instead of `xterm`. [The `lxterminal` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/lxterminal.1.html) accepts `-e` and treats it the same way as `xterm`, so this would look like `lxterminal -e python /path/to/script/py`. As with XTerm, LXTerminal will quit when the  command is finished running.